# Velodyne lidar lasers see through checkerboards

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I created a velodyne lidar with this tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i1
In my tests I also need checkerboards to be present, but lidar laseds just pierce then and return inf range value.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27304/velodyne-lidar-lasers-see-through-checkerboards/) by [Egor Chubarov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/50728/egor-chubarov/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-08-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is your Velodyne a `ray` sensor or a `gpu_ray` sensor?

If it's `ray`, the sensor detects objects by their collisions, so you need to add collision of the same shape as your checkerboard. If it's `gpu_ray`, the sensor detects objects by their visuals, and collision is not needed.

---

Originally posted by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) with karma: 226 on 2021-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3